# Adding to New context menu item in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I right click within an Explorer window, down in 'New' I of course have the option to create a new folder, text file, etc. there. I would like to add the option of opening a cmd 'black box' window in the directory in which I right clicked. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Something like this?  http://www.petri.co.il/add_command_prompt_here_shortcut_to_windows_explorer.htm

Comment: Yes, thanks. I also just learned that in Windows 7 (which is what I should have mentioned I am using), I can hold the shift key and then right-click on a folder and see the option to open a command prompt with that folder as the current directory.

Comment: If you found something that answered your question there, you might want to add that as an answer, then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned the answer that works on Windows 7. Holding the shift key and then right-clicking on a folder causes the option "Open command window here" to be available. You have to right-click on a folder icon of the directory you want to open a command window in, not just in Windows Explorer's right pane in the folder you want to open the command window in.